# Was Moksha (liberation) not considered as one of the Purusharthas in Ramayana period?

Tags: ramayana, purushartha

In ***5th Sarga*** of Bala Kanda of Ramayana, I have stumbled upon the following sloka (4th).

> तदिदं वर्तयिष्यावः सर्वं निखिलमादितः | **धर्मकामार्थसहितं**
>   श्रोतव्यमनसूयया || १-५-४
>
> Being such a legend, we two wish to relate this Ramayana entirely and
>   completely from the beginning, which is endowed with the values and
>   means of **probity, prosperity, and pleasure seeking**... and this be
>   listened without any caviling.

Sage Valmiki was mentioning about the Ramayana is about only 3 Purusharthas, ie.,  probity, prosperity, and pleasure seeking only - धर्मकामार्थसहितं, but not about Moksha.

**Was Moksha (liberation) not considered as one of the Purusharthas in Ramayana period?**

Comment: I don't know what they think about.   As far as I understood,  Ramayana was composed at the post vedic period.  Brahmanas might be already in place and Prajapati was already personified as Brahma - brahma lOkAdhipo yatha, but Valmiki was influenced by the Veda and Shadangas only

Comment: Well if Purusha sukta in Rig Veda talks about liberation then why will moksha not be considered as one of the Purusharthas at time of Ramayana. Just so happens it is not explicitly stated but the entire incidents - be it killing of demons in forest or Ravana as well as death of Jatayu - they all point towards liberations

Comment: At many places there is mention of only 1 / 2 / 3 / 4...see [this](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga48/aranyasans48.htm#Verse24), it seems to be talking about moksha as ultimate goal/purushartha...